# Grouping rectangles horizontally and vertically

Tags: c#, computational-geometry, clustering

As you can see the below code for each method is that same, except for the properties it uses. For example `X` vs `Y` and `Width` vs `Height`. Is there anyway that I can refactor the code to use a common main method that changes on which property it uses?

**Notes:**

The all caps constant is `BOX_LINEUP_TOLERANCE` has a value of `0.15f` and is all caps due to a company policy.

The two methods:

```
private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectanglesHorizontally(Rectangle[] rectangles, out int averageGap)
{
    List<int> nlGaps = new List<int>();
    List<Rectangle[]> rectangleGroups = new List<Rectangle[]>();
    for (int bi = 0, bc = rectangles.Length; bi < bc; ++bi)
    {
        if (rectangleGroups.Any(g => g.Contains(rectangles[bi])))
        {
            continue;
        }

        int nTolerance = (int)Math.Ceiling(rectangles[bi].Height * BOX_LINEUP_TOLERANCE);
        Rectangle[] baSimiliarHeight = rectangles.Where(b => Math.Abs(b.Y - rectangles[bi].Y) <= nTolerance
                                                            && b.X > rectangles[bi].X)
                                                    .ToArray();
        if (baSimiliarHeight.Length <= 1)
        {
            rectangleGroups.Add(new Rectangle[] { rectangles[bi] });
            continue;
        }
        baSimiliarHeight = baSimiliarHeight.OrderBy(b => b.X).ToArray();

        int nInitialGap = baSimiliarHeight[0].X - (rectangles[bi].X + rectangles[bi].Width);
        int nInitialGapTolerance = (int)Math.Ceiling(nInitialGap * BOX_LINEUP_TOLERANCE);
        nlGaps.Add(nInitialGap);

        List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new List<Rectangle>();
        rectangleList.Add(rectangles[bi]);
        rectangleList.Add(baSimiliarHeight[0]);

        for (int sbi = 1; sbi < baSimiliarHeight.Length; ++sbi)
        {
            int nGap = baSimiliarHeight[sbi].X - (baSimiliarHeight[sbi - 1].X + baSimiliarHeight[sbi - 1].Width);
            if (nGap <= nInitialGap + nInitialGapTolerance && nGap >= nInitialGap - nInitialGapTolerance)
            {
                rectangleList.Add(baSimiliarHeight[sbi]);
                nlGaps.Add(nGap);
            }
            else if (nGap > nInitialGap)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //Initial gap was larger so first rectangle is in its own group
                rectangleList = new List<Rectangle>(new Rectangle[] { rectangles[bi] });
                break;
            }
        }

        rectangleGroups.Add(rectangleList.ToArray());
    }

    averageGap = (int)nlGaps.Average();
    return rectangleGroups;
}

private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectanglesVertically(Rectangle[] rectangles, out int averageGap)
{
    List<int> nlGaps = new List<int>();
    List<Rectangle[]> rectangleGroups = new List<Rectangle[]>();
    for (int bi = 0, bc = rectangles.Length; bi < bc; ++bi)
    {
        if (rectangleGroups.Any(g => g.Contains(rectangles[bi])))
        {
            continue;
        }

        int nTolerance = (int)Math.Ceiling(rectangles[bi].Width * BOX_LINEUP_TOLERANCE);
        Rectangle[] baSimiliarWidth = rectangles.Where(b => Math.Abs(b.X - rectangles[bi].X) <= nTolerance
                                                            && b.Y > rectangles[bi].Y)
                                                .ToArray();
        if (baSimiliarWidth.Length <= 1)
        {
            rectangleGroups.Add(new Rectangle[] { rectangles[bi] });
            continue;
        }
        baSimiliarWidth = baSimiliarWidth.OrderBy(b => b.Y).ToArray();

        int nInitialGap = baSimiliarWidth[0].Y - (rectangles[bi].Y + rectangles[bi].Height);
        int nInitialGapTolerance = (int)Math.Ceiling(nInitialGap * BOX_LINEUP_TOLERANCE);
        nlGaps.Add(nInitialGap);

        List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new List<Rectangle>();
        rectangleList.Add(rectangles[bi]);
        rectangleList.Add(baSimiliarWidth[0]);

        for (int sbi = 1; sbi < baSimiliarWidth.Length; ++sbi)
        {
            int nGap = baSimiliarWidth[sbi].Y - (baSimiliarWidth[sbi - 1].Y + baSimiliarWidth[sbi - 1].Height);
            if (nGap <= nInitialGap + nInitialGapTolerance && nGap >= nInitialGap - nInitialGapTolerance)
            {
                rectangleList.Add(baSimiliarWidth[sbi]);
                nlGaps.Add(nGap);
            }
            else if (nGap > nInitialGap)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                //Initial gap was larger so first rectangle is in its own group
                rectangleList = new List<Rectangle>(new Rectangle[] { rectangles[bi] });
                break;
            }
        }

        rectangleGroups.Add(rectangleList.ToArray());
    }

    averageGap = (int)nlGaps.Average();
    return rectangleGroups;
}
```

I will also appreciate general feedback about the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a boolean as a parameter and select X or Y and Width or Height based on that parameter.  You can declare the method like this:

```
private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectangles(Rectangle[] rectangles, bool horizontally, out int averageGap)
```

You can use the code from the horizontal method and modify the property calls to use the boolean.  For example, you would replace `rectangle.X` with `horizontally ? rectangle.X : rectangle.Y` and `rectangle.Width` with `horizontally ? rectangle.Width : rectangle.Height`.

It can then be used in your previous methods:

```
private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectanglesHorizontally(Rectangle[] rectangles, out int averageGap)
{
    return GroupRectangles(rectangles, true, out averageGap);
}


private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectanglesVertically(Rectangle[] rectangles, out int averageGap)
{
    return GroupRectangles(rectangles, false, out averageGap);
}
```

Alternatively, you could have functions as parameters for selecting the properties, like using a lambda expression in `OrderBy()`.

Edit: as for the first method itself:

In the following line of code:

```
Rectangle[] baSimiliarHeight = rectangles.Where(b => Math.Abs(b.Y - rectangles[bi].Y) <= nTolerance
                                                        && b.X > rectangles[bi].X)
                                                .ToArray();
```

it won't get rectangles that are at the exact same X position.  But that won't matter if it's guaranteed that none of the rectangles overlap.  Then there's this code right after:

```
if (baSimiliarHeight.Length <= 1)
{
    rectangleGroups.Add(new Rectangle[] { rectangles[bi] });
    continue;
}
```

Because rectangles with the same X position weren't matched before, `baSimiliarHeight` won't contain `rectangles[bi]`, so if it has a length of 1, that 1 element will be a different rectangle, but only the original rectangle will get added as a group.

In the inner `for` loop, the body of the last `else` only adds the initial rectangle, but doesn't do anything about the previously added `nGap`s, so it's possible for the loop to add a bunch of `nGaps` but only add the initial rectangle.

If you get a list of the rectangles ordered by their X position right away and loop through that instead of the original list, you can take some shortcuts in the body of the `for` loop.

Edit 2:

You should add more descriptive names.  I don't know what `bi`, `bc`, the nl in `nlGaps`, etc. stand for.  Short names are okay for lambda expressions and loop variables, but even then you should stick to `x`, `y`, `i`, `j`, or a letter that relates to the object.  I think it would make more sense to use `r` for a rectangle than `b`.

Comment: Some good help, the `b`b is used because my code uses a different data structure a `Box` but the only part of that structure that is relvant is the `Rectangle` so I changed the code slightly. Just forgot to change the bs to rs

Answer (score 3):

To keep your code clean, you could define delegates:

```
delegate int AxisLocationDelegate(Rectangle r, bool primaryAxis);
delegate int AxisSizeDelegate(Rectangle r, bool primaryAxis);
```

Then define a unified `GroupRectanglesBy` function that takes an implementation of each of these delegates as parameters:

```
private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectanglesBy(Rectangle[] rectangles,
    AxisLocationDelegate getLocation, AxisSizeDelegate getSize, out int averageGap)
{
    // ...
```

Here in the main function you could refer to the delegate functions `getLocation` and `getSize` and specify whether you're interested in the primary or secondary axis, e.g.:

```
    int nTolerance = (int)Math.Ceiling(getSize(rectangles[bi], false) * BOX_LINEUP_TOLERANCE);
    Rectangle[] baSimiliarMagnitude = rectangles.Where(
        b => Math.Abs(getLocation(b, false) - getSize(rectangles[bi], false)) <= nTolerance
                && getLocation(b, true) > getLocation(rectangles[bi], true))
        .ToArray();
```

Then call with horizontal/vertical implementations of the delegates that pick out the relevant properties:

```
private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectanglesHorizontally(Rectangle[] rectangles, out int averageGap)
{
    return GroupRectanglesBy(
        rectangles,
        (rect, primaryAxis) => primaryAxis ? rect.Location.X : rect.Location.Y,
        (rect, primaryAxis) => primaryAxis ? rect.Width : rect.Height,
        out averageGap);
}

private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectanglesVertically(Rectangle[] rectangles, out int averageGap)
{
    return GroupRectanglesBy(
        rectangles,
        (rect, primaryAxis) => primaryAxis ? rect.Location.Y : rect.Location.X,
        (rect, primaryAxis) => primaryAxis ? rect.Height : rect.Width,
        out averageGap);
}
```

Edit: if you were feeling particularly evil and wanted to use the boolean XOR operator `^`, you could even reduce this to one function:

```
private List<Rectangle[]> GroupRectangles(Rectangle[] rectangles, bool vertically, out int averageGap)
{
    return GroupRectanglesBy(
        rectangles,
        (rect, primaryAxis) => primaryAxis ^ vertically ? rect.Location.X : rect.Location.Y,
        (rect, primaryAxis) => primaryAxis ^ vertically ? rect.Width : rect.Height,
        out averageGap);
}
```